# MySQL string manipulations and data rearranging

Tags: mysql, sql

Due to multiple legacy systems, a project I'm working on has a table consisting of 10 columns.

Of these 10 columns, two pieces of data will always appear in two of the last five columns, preceeded by an identifying string.

The last 5 columns are `pair0`, `pair1`, `pair2`, `pair3`, and `pair4`

The format of the data I'm looking for in two of those five columns is `tx-speed=3D...` and `rx-speed=3D...`. Following each of those strings is a series of digits of arbitrary length.

I cannot modify the programs that insert data into this table, I can only modify it afterwards.

In every row, existing and future, I want to make sure that the series of digits following `tx-speed=3D` is in the `pair1` column and that the series of digits following `rx-speed=3D` is in the `pair2` column. The contents of those two columns is not important to keep, so long as the `tx-speed` and `rx-speed` values don't overwrite each other.

As an unfortunate constraint of the project, this can't be done on a database trigger, it must be as part of a cron job or similar.

My big problem here is I am not a SQL Administrator. I could script it in one of many available languages, but efficiency is going to be key and pulling the data out of SQL to inspect it and reinsert it from a different platform is going to be very inefficient.

I started to try to write a SQL script to do this, but I don't understand nearly enough about how SQL works to even get it working.

To (hopefully) clarify a bit, I've put together the following pseudocode in the hope that someone would be able to make a SQL query out of this that I could use for my purpose.

```
for each row:

@tx = ""
@rx = ""
txstr = "tx-speed=3D"
rxstr = "rx-speed=3D"
if (pair0 LIKE txstr+"%")
  @tx = SUBSTRING(pair0, FROM txstr.count-1)
elsif (pair1 LIKE txstr+"%")
  @tx = SUBSTRING(pair0, FROM txstr.count-1)
elsif (pair2 LIKE txstr+"%")
  ...
endif
if (pair0 LIKE rxstr+"%")
  @rx = SUBSTRING(pair0, FROM rxstr.count-1)
elsif (pair1 LIKE rxstr+"%")
  ...
endif

pair1 = @tx
pair2 = @rx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to create a stored procedure (you said you can't create triggers):

```
delimiter //

drop procedure curdemo  
//

create procedure curdemo()
begin
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  declare p0 char(20);
  declare p1 char(20);
  declare p2 char(20);
  declare p3 char(20);
  declare p4 char(20);
  declare a mediumint;
  declare cur1 cursor for select id,pair0,pair1,pair2,pair3,pair4 from test.t2;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  open cur1;

  read_loop: loop
    fetch cur1 into a,p0,p1,p2,p3,p4;
    if done then
        leave read_loop;
    end if;
    if p0 like 'tx-speed=3D%' then
        update t2 set pair1 = substring_index(p0, 'tx-speed=3D', -1)
            where id = a;
    elseif p1 like 'tx-speed=3D%' then
                update t2 set pair1 = substring_index(p1, 'tx-speed=3D', -1)
            where id = a;
        elseif p2 like 'tx-speed=3D%' then
                update t2 set pair1 = substring_index(p2, 'tx-speed=3D', -1)
            where id = a;
    end if;

        if p0 like 'rx-speed=3D%' then
                update t2 set pair2 = substring_index(p0, 'rx-speed=3D', -1)
            where id = a;
        elseif p1 like 'rx-speed=3D%' then
                update t2 set pair2 = substring_index(p1, 'rx-speed=3D', -1)
            where id = a;
        elseif p2 like 'rx-speed=3D%' then
                update t2 set pair2 = substring_index(p2, 'rx-speed=3D', -1)
            where id = a;
        end if;
  end loop;
  close cur1;
end
//

drop table t2 //
create table t2 (
    id mediumint not null auto_increment,
    pair0 varchar(20),
    pair1 varchar(20),
    pair2 varchar(20),
    pair3 varchar(20),
    pair4 varchar(20),
    primary key(id)
)
//
insert into t2 (pair0, pair1) values ('tx-speed=3D1230', 'rx-speed=3D1231') //
insert into t2 (pair0, pair2) values ('tx-speed=3D1232', 'rx-speed=3D1233') //
insert into t2 (pair4, pair3) values ('tx-speed=3D1233', 'rx-speed=3D1235') //
insert into t2 (pair2, pair3) values ('tx-speed=3D1236', 'rx-speed=3D1237') //

select * from t2 //

call curdemo()
//

select * from t2 //
```

Your cron job would just be the "call curdemo()" part. Your table needs some sort of rowid.

If that doesn't work, pulling the data out and inspecting it on a different platform is what you are left with because you will be processing the data in the 'mysql' client app... so you might as well do it in a language you are comfortable with.